# A question about convex polyhedra

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let S be a sphere of unit radius in three dimensional Euclidean space, R^3. Given a
positive real number e, does there always exist a convex polyhedron P in R^3 such that:
(1) S is a subset of P (2) The boundary of P is homeomorphic to the boundary of S (3) The
volume of P does not exceed the volume of S by more than e? It is not required that S be
tangent to any of the faces of P.

Comment: (2) S has no boundary, so I assume you mean boundary of P is homeomorphic to S.

Otherwise, the answer is YES, and this looks an awful lot like a homework problem.


Comment: I interpreted "sphere" to mean "ball".  I would not have answered except the OP gives his name and has asked some reasonable questions in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small $\epsilon$ let $Q$ be the convex symmetric hull of a finite $\epsilon$ net for the boundary of $S$ and let $P=(1+\epsilon) Q$.

Comment: To Bill Johnson: I should have written  "ball" instead oF "sphere".
Your answer beautifully clarified for me what should be the right
approach to the problem. If we begin with a ball B concentric to S
whose volume exceeds that of S by exactly e, then by taking a small
enough positive number v, it should be possible to prove the existence of a finite v-net for B whose convex hull, H, contains 
S as a subset. Then H is the sought for polyhedron.

Answer (score 9):

This is proposition 17 of book 12 of Euclid's elements.

Comment: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookXII/propXII17.html

Comment: @Scott. Proof that you can make a trivial problem hard if you look at it the wrong way.  :)